# How to normlize audio file in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a couple of audio files that want to normalize at .`-1dB`,  any idea how may I do that. 
PS: I'm not asking how to read them, consider  they are all saved in the Workspace as : `A1 A2 A3 etc`
**UPDATE**
[image: plot]
thanks to Neil for his comment, here an example of two files , as you can see the signal aren't on the same level , ( that causes problems when try to any their PSD, so I would like to get all the file at the same level as far I know that called normalization.  I can do that in Audacity but not in Matlab, because I don't know and the mathematics behind it.

thanks for your help

Comment: What problems are you having with normalising? Could you show code for manipulating the audio you have so far?

Comment: @Neil the problem is that I don't know how to do ,  multiples vector in my work-space that I need to normalize to -1dB

Comment: Please take some time to show the code you do have, and give more than "I don't know how to do it". What *do* you know about normalising audio, where's the gap in your knowledge that a good answer would fill? If you take time to explain that it will make the question a better fit to SO, and more likely to get the answer you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normalising an audio waveform involves:

- Choosing the desired norm. You have more choices than just the maximum offset, but that is the simplest. If your representation is sample values in range -1.0 to 1.0, then normalising to -1dB is actually saying you want all values to be between -0.891 and 0.891 ([from Wikipedia article on Decibel)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel)
- Finding the current absolute maximum value. You can use e.g. `max(abs( A1(:) ) )` for that
- Multiplying all values such that the maximum is now limited to the new top value. Multiplication is the correct operation due to the representation used by most raw audio signals.

So, in theory, you want something like:

```
A1_norm = A1 * 0.891 / max( abs( A1(:) ) );
```

Comment: Well thought, i would have forgotten to use `abs()` and therefor ignoring the negative values...